# Proving that ${n\choose 1}+3{n\choose 3}+5{n\choose 5}+\ldots=2{n\choose 2}+4{n\choose 4}+6{n\choose 6}+\ldots$

Tags: combinatorics

I recently came upon a problem in a textbook that asks to show that $${n \choose 1} +3{n \choose 3} +5{n \choose 5} +\ldots = 2{n \choose 2} +4{n \choose 4} + 6{n \choose 6} +\ldots$$ using a counting argument. I’ve tried solving this using the idea that each side can be written as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k{n \choose k},$$ where $k$ is only odd on the left-hand side and even on the right-. My current way of thinking of this problem is that you are choosing $k$ elements from a set of $n$, and of these $k$ elements, one is special in some way. However, I don’t understand how the number of ways that can be put together with only odd-numbered $k$s is equivalent to even-numbered $k$s. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ Hi, it does not. I am still a bit confused as to how to wrap my head around this problem using a counting argument.

Answer (score 5):

Let's write

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} x^k = (1-x)^n$$

Take the derivative and get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1} = n (1-x)^{n-1} \cdot (-1)$$
Now take $x=1$.

$\bf{Added:}$ We could try to generalize this method. Say we take $m$ derivatives of the binomial equality. We get

$$\sum_{k} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k k(k-1)\cdot \cdots \cdot (k-m+1) x^{k-m} = (-1)^m n(n-1) \cdots (n-m+1)(1-x)^{n-m} $$

For $n> m$, the RHS is $0$ at $x=1$, and so will be the LHS.

We see that it is all very similar to the proof of

$$\sum_{k} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} = 0$$
for $n> 0$ integer.

$\bf{Added:}$ It is definitely worth looking again at the equality above.

Say we have a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $N$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} P(x+k)$$

is a polynomial of degree $N-n$.  Indeed, it equals the [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)

$$(\Delta^n P) (x)$$
where $\Delta P (x) = P(x+1)-P(x)$. So now we have another method, and a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Define a "pointed $k$-set" to be a nonempty $k$-set $S$ with a chosen element $x\in S$. The number of all pointed $k$-sets in an $n$-set is $k {n\choose k}$. So you want to show that the number of all odd pointed subsets is equal to the number of even pointed subsets.

If $n$ is even, then $(x, S) \mapsto (x, (n-S) \cup \{x\})$ could work. For instance, if $n=4$, then

$(2, \{1,2\}) \leftrightarrow (2, \{0,2,3\})$

If $n$ is odd, then pointed set split to three parts: (a) those that contain $0$ and is pointed at $0$, (b) those that contain $0$ and is pointed elsewhere, and (c) those that do not contain $0$.

both (b) and (c) reduces to the even case (0 can be just ignored).

(a) reduces to simple non-pointed set counting (sets with even number of elements = sets with odd number of elements), after excluding $0$.

Sadly, I couldn't find a neater argument for the odd case.

Comment: Great idea!   So it reduces to showing the sum with $k^0$ (instead of $1$) is $0$ ?

Comment: This is the same problem as with unpointed subsets, the bijection $S \leftrightarrow [n] - S$ only works if $n$ is odd. You want something like $S \leftrightarrow S \Delta \{1\}$, as in @BrianMoehring's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 2$, let $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and
$$\mathcal{A} = \{(a,A) \in [n] \times \mathcal{P}([n]) : a \in A\}.$$  Then define $f : \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{A}$ by $$f(a,A) = \begin{cases}(a,A\Delta\{1\}) & \text{ if } a\neq 1\\ (1,A\Delta\{2\}) & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
where $A \Delta B := (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is the symmetric difference.

We can show directly that $f\circ f(a,A) = (a,A)$, so $f$ is bijective.
Additionally, it's a routine exercise to show that the even/odd parity of elements in $A$ is always the opposite parity of $A \Delta \{x\}$.

If we additionally define
$$\mathcal{A}_\text{odd} = \{(a,A) \in \mathcal{A} : |A| \text{ is odd}\}, \\ \mathcal{A}_\text{even} = \{(a,A) \in \mathcal{A} : |A| \text{ is even}\}$$
then the above shows that $f$ induces a bijection $\mathcal{A}_\text{odd} \to \mathcal{A}_\text{even}$.  To finish, it suffices to show that $$|\mathcal{A}_\text{even}| = \sum_{k=2 \\ k \text{ even}}^n k\binom{n}{k}, \qquad |\mathcal{A}_\text{odd}| = \sum_{k=1 \\ k \text{ odd}}^n k\binom{n}{k}$$